# Convert double[] to long[]

Tags: java, arrays, double, long-integer

Well like the title says, I have to convert a `double[]` to a `long[]` but I don't know how can I do it.

I try this:

```
double[] ids = getIds(); // The ids I'm getting return in double format
List<Long> myArray = new ArrayList<Long>();

for (double _ids : ids) {
    myArray.add((long)_ids);
}

System.out.println(myArray); // Works! the list is now long, I can print also in myArray.toArray()

// Now I need pass this on a long[] array for the system wich request the data
// Receive "getStringsById(String string, long... Ids)"
```

I really appreciate the help.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why are you creating `List<Long>` instead of `long[]` directly?

Comment: a `List<Long>` is not `long[]`

Answer (score 5):

Create a `long[]` instead of creating a `List<Long>`, which would need a call to `toArray()` to get a `long[]`.

```
long[] myArray = new long[ids.length];
int i = 0;
for (double _ids : ids){
    myArray[i++] = (long) _ids;
}
```